# How to skip NULL file

Tags: c

My code traverses through command line arguments. if the command line contains "alice.txt" index zero of an empty array is filled with "alice.txt" This also applies to "anh.txt" if it is present, then index 1 is filled with "anh.txt". When i type in the command line ./wc alice.txt anh.txt it will print out words line and characters of both files. however if I just do /wc anh.txt i will get "NULL FILE" I suspect this is because of index zero being NULL, I wrote it so it would print "NULL FILE" and then exit the program. How can I modify my code so it doesn't exit, rather skips to the next index? This is what I have for code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int argArray[argc];
        char *nameArray[argc];


        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
        {
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-l") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[0] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[1] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0)
                {
                        argArray[2] = 1;
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "alice.txt") == 0)
                {
                        nameArray[0] = "alice.txt";
                }
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "anh.txt") == 0)
                {
                        nameArray[1] = "anh.txt";
                }

                if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-l") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") != 0 ) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") != 0 ) && (strcmp(argv[i], "-w") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "alice.txt") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[i], "anh.txt") != 0))
                {
                        printf("%s is an invalid argument or file\n", argv[i]);
                }
        }
        if ((argArray[0] != 1) && (argArray[1] != 1) && (argArray[2] != 1))
        {
                argArray[0] = 1;
                argArray[1] = 1;
                argArray[2] = 1;
        }

        int *myArrayAlice = get_counts2(nameArray[0]);
        print_counts(argArray, myArrayAlice, *nameArray);
        printf(" alice.txt\n");

        int *myArrayAnh = get_counts(nameArray[1]);
        print_counts(argArray,myArrayAnh, *nameArray);
        printf(" anh.txt\n");
        int *myArrayTotal2 = get_counts2(nameArray[1]);
        print_counts(argArray, myArrayTotal2, *nameArray);
        printf(" total\n");
        return 0;
}
int *get_counts(char *filename)
{

        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
                printf("NULL FILE");
                //exit(1);
        }

        int c;
        bool whitespace = true;
        int *arr = calloc(3,sizeof(int));
        for(;;)
        {
                c = fgetc(file);
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                        break;
                }
                else if (c == '\n')
                {
                        arr[0]++;
                }
                else if (whitespace && !isspace(c))
                {
                        arr[1]++;
                        whitespace = false;
                }
                else if (!whitespace && isspace(c))
                {
                        whitespace = true;
                }
                arr[2]++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return arr;
}
int *get_counts2(char *filename)
{

        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
                printf("NULL FILE");
                //exit(1);
        }

        int c;
        bool whitespace = true;
        static int arr[3] = {0,0,0};
        for(;;)
        {
                c = fgetc(file);
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                        break;
                }
                else if (c == '\n')
                {
                        arr[0]++;
                }
                else if (whitespace && !isspace(c))
                {
                        arr[1]++;
                        whitespace = false;
                }
                else if (!whitespace && isspace(c))
                {
                        whitespace = true;
                }
                arr[2]++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep a count of the number of files instead of hard coding the indexes? That is, `int count = 0;` then do `argArray[count++] = argv[i]`. Finally, you just need a loop that uses `count` to know how many files to process.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html if file is null, `errno` will hold an error indicator, and `perror` can write out a description of the failure.  NULL FILE for you could be permission denied, file not found , other reasons too.

Comment: `./wc anh.txt` means the file in the current directory, but `/wc anh.txt` means the file located in the `/` (root) directory. Since there is no `/wc anh.txt` when you attempt to open it, the open fails returning a `NULL` pointer from `fopen()`. You then blindly read from the invalid file stream invoking *Undefined Behavior*. You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***.